# react-cookie-consent does not work on html pages in public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am using `react-cookies-consent` to display cookies and it is working without any problem on every component until I needed to add HTML pages to the public folder for SEO reasons now the cookies consent will not be displayed on these pages. Any suggestion on how should I approach this problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { render } from 'react-snapshot';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from "./routes";

import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.css';
import CookieBanner from "./CookieBanner";
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import C5 from "./images/konfigurator/C5.webp";
import HelmetMetaData from "./HelmetMetaData";


render(
      <React.StrictMode>
          <Router>
              <CookieBanner />
                <Routes />
              {/*<App />*/}
          </Router>
      </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();


class Routes extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <HelmetMetaData />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => {window.location.href="Home.html"}} />
                <Route path="/Main" component={App}/>
                <Route path="/About" render={() => {window.location.href="About.html"}}/>
                <Route path="/impressum" render={() => {window.location.href="impressum.html"}}/>
                <Route path="/blog" render={() => {window.location.href="blog.html"}}/>
                <Route path="/Questions" render={() => {window.location.href="Questions.html"}} />
                <Route path="/Answers" render={() => {window.location.href="Answers.html"}} />
                <Route path="/info" render={() => {window.location.href="info.html"}} />
                <Route component={Error}/>
            </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
export default Routes;
```

**Update:**

I just tried the possibility to render a component in HTML page I started with a simple example but it doesn't work

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/jsx">
    var NewComponent = React.createClass({
        render : function (){
            return (
                <h1>New year welcoming</h1>
            )
        }
    })
    ReactDOM.render(<NewComponent />, document.getElementById('banner'));
</script>

</body>
```

Yes i included `<div id="banner"></div>` just right after the `<body>`

No errors given it just doesn`t render

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're basically talking about having a mixed-domain. One SPA (your React app) and some non-spa HTML pages.

To make this work you'd have to run React in both scenarios, which is what you've tried in the last picture.

I would recommend foregoing the "HTML" pages route, it is difficult to maintain. Instead, you can use [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) to create those few static pages. You can even re-use components between your existing React code-base and the React-based Gatsby part.

Using static HTML pages doesn't improve SEO by default. If you're running into performance problems you should have a look at Server-side-rendering or static site generation (like Gatsby)